# The URL couldn't be validated. Response does not match challenge, expected value="802376652", received="null"

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, facebook-webhooks, whatsapp-cloud-api

When I am trying to configure meta webhook using AWS API as callback URL for my lambda function, I am getting an error: The URL couldn't be validated. Response does not match challenge, expected value="802376652", received="null"

Here is my lambda function code:

```
app_secret = os.environ['APP_SECRET']
verify_token = os.environ['VERIFY_TOKEN']
app_token = os.environ['APP_TOKEN']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if "httpMethod" in event and event["httpMethod"] == "GET":
        query_params = event.get("queryStringParameters", {})
        mode = query_params.get("hub.mode")
        token = query_params.get("hub.verify_token")
        challenge = query_params.get("hub.challenge")
        
        if mode and token and mode == "subscribe" and token == verify_token:
            return {
                "statusCode": 200,
                "body": challenge
            }
        else:
            return {
                "statusCode": 403
            }
            


    elif "httpMethod" in event and event["httpMethod"] == "POST":
        body = json.loads(event["body"])
        if "object" in body and body["object"] == "page":
            for entry in body.get("entry", []):
                if "messaging" in entry:
                    for messaging_event in entry["messaging"]:
                        if "message" in messaging_event:
                            sender_id = messaging_event["sender"]["id"]
                            userText = messaging_event["message"]["text"]
                            handle_message(sender_id, userText)
            return {"statusCode": 200}
        else:
            return {"statusCode": 400}



def verify_signature(request_payload, signature_header):
    signature = hmac.new(app_secret.encode(), request_payload, hashlib.sha1).hexdigest()
    return signature == signature_header.split('=')[1]




def handle_message(sender_id, userText):
```

#MyfurtherCodes

Kindly check and suggest any solution that why I am not able to configure my AWS API as callback URL in meta webhook.

Note: (1). I haven't used any auth in AWS API, just set environmental variables as I have mentioned in lambda function code.
(2). I used python language for writing my lambda function code.